# animating one element when hovering over another

Tags: css

In the following code I am trying to get the train ticket to rotate when I hover over a leaf.

I can get the train ticket to rotate when I hover over it but not when I hover over the leaf.
Can anyone spot what is wrong with what I have written?

In my CSS file:

```
#leaf{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    }
#leaf:hover ~ #trainticket {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skew(45deg) translate(0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    }

#trainticket{
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 175px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#trainticket:hover{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skew(45deg) translate(0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    }
```

And in my HTML file:

```
    <div>
      <a target="bio" href="bio1.html">
      <img ID="leaf" src="leaftrans1.png" 
      style="position:absolute;
      display:block;
      top: 30px; 
      left: 30px; 
      width:10%; 
      height:10%;"></a>

    <div>
      <img ID="trainticket" src="current-train-ticket.jpg">
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Note that `#leaf` and `#trainticket` are NOT siblings. Considering the given markup you can use `a[href="bio1.html"]:hover + div > #trainticket` selector instead.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when you want to do complicated animations, you should consider using JavaScript (with jQuery for instance). Triggering an animation on an element when hovering over another is complicated enough to consider using jQuery: CSS is in my opinion not the right tool for this kind of stuff (at least at the moment), and you'll probably end up using a lot of hacks to achieve this and to make it compatible with all browsers.

Comment: Actually the issue was related to the used selector, not to the CSS `transition`.

Comment: This was actually a "meta-answer", not answering the question at all I must admit. I just wanted to warn the OP about the use of transition in CSS, which is not always the best solution due to how tricky it can get, and because of the lack of support in some browsers. jQuery is usally a better solution, as it handles the browser compatibility itself without much performance loss (i.e. it will use the CSS3 transition if available), while keeping it simple.

Comment: You should go ahead and post your answer as a real answer instead of a comment, as it really answers the question :)

Comment: I usually post simple answers as comments :) Maybe I'm wrong but this question doesn't make me feel posting an answer :)

Comment: I am a newbie to writing web pages. On this occasion I have achieved the effect using CSS to specify what the effect looks like and jQuery toggle to add the class to trigger the event. I'm quite surprised how easy jQuery is...not scary at all.

Comment: That's exactly why it's so popular :-)